# ActionBarActivity with SearchView

Tags: java, android, android-actionbaractivity

I have a working search implementation using the Search Widget like so inside of an activity that extends from `Activity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_results, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = 
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = 
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

    if(null!=searchManager) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    }
    return true;
}
```

When changing the activity to extend `ActionBarActivity`, I get this null pointer:

```
10-10 15:51:49.044: E/AndroidRuntime(19406): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 15:51:49.044: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at com.example.myapp.SearchResultsActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(SearchResultsActivity.java:114)
10-10 15:51:49.044: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2546)
10-10 15:51:49.044: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:224)
10-10 15:51:49.044: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:232)
10-10 15:51:49.044: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146)
10-10 15:51:49.044: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:199)
10-10 15:51:49.044: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293)
10-10 15:51:49.044: E/AndroidRuntime(19406):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:436)
```

I do have other ActionBarActivities that work perfectly (though not with a search widget) in my app and I did a project clean with no results. Why am I getting this null pointer in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ActionBarActivity`, you need to use [MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#getActionProvider(android.view.MenuItem)) along with [android.support.v7.widget.SearchView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.html) (not the framework SearchView) as per the [Action Bar Action View guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView).

Comment: I've done all of that and the thing still won't show, just dismisses the keyboard and sits there, even the logs from startActivity (overridden to start activity for the search result) won't show

Comment: Thanks a lot - saved my day!! **ActionBarActivity** needs *android.support.v7.widget.SearchView* and a link to the guide - great!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [complete solution](http://antonioleiva.com/actionbarcompat-action-views/) behind what ianhanniballake mentioned above

You have to set OnQueryTextListener on the searchView that you get from MenuItemCompat and then open the activity yourself with the search term that is passed to you from the listener. Tested and works